# Phantom Power Issue

Tags: microphone, phantom, home

Quick question about phantom power. I know while using full consoles, you want to make sure phantom is off, before plugging in a condenser mic, and the track is muted before turning phantom on, but what about with daws. I've recently found myself quitting Pro Tools or Logic without turning phantom off from my interface. I'm assuming the same rules still apply. Anyone know? Please and thanks in advance.

Comment: The DAW doesn't have turning phantom power on and off, the audio interface does. But yes, there are still reasons to mute channels before turning phantom power on or off.

Answer (score 1):

The audio software is not impressed by phantom power except when you turn it on/off when already recording.  In which case its peak detection might be seriously off when normalizing your tracks unless you cut out the resulting spikes.

Hardware, however, namely input circuits and microphones might be less happy.  Again, this has very little to do with the DAW unless phantom power is software-controlled.  Even then, it will more likely be a separate utility rather than your DAW that allows you to switch phantom power on/off.  There still is usually at least one physical switch for turning off all phantom power: software control is usually only used for turning off phantom power on specific inputs over the course of multiple recording sessions (because you generally use them for dynamic or ribbon mics).

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Phantom Power (48V) shouldn't effect your DAW at all. It is more of a voltage thing so it will be affecting hardware.